# How to load the data from .json file in httplistener

Tags: javascript, json, httplistener

I'm a new on WebService/JavaScript development environment. I got a task - current our HttpListener code serves the localhost request for .js file. What I need is capable of putting json objects around in HttpListener.

- Receiving value types, objects and List (or array) from a JSON file (.json) and converts a JSON string into a JavaScript object
- Sending value types, objects and List to the JavaScript
- Outputting above json data to the console

It would be great if you can share any ideas/solution how to implement on this.

Here's our code currently works with .js - HttpListener.cs:

```
private static void Main()
{
var server = new HttpListener();
server.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:80/");

server.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

while (true)
{
   HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
   HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

   string fileId = string.Empty;
   try
   {
   string page = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), context.Request.Url.LocalPath.Replace("/", @"\").Substring(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Get request from {0}", page);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(page) && !page.EndsWith(".js"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("file is not a .js file.");
        continue;
    }

      // Check requested file really exists

      // Get file id property from the query string.
      fileId = context.Request.QueryString["fileid"];

      string msg;
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(page))
      {
           msg = sr.ReadToEnd();
      }

      byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
      response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
      response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

      using (Stream st = response.OutputStream)
      {
           Console.WriteLine(buffer.Length);
           st.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
           context.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";
           Console.WriteLine("Request done:{0}", fileId);
      }
      catch { } // suppress any exceptions
      finally
      {
           context.Response.Close();
           Console.WriteLine("Response closed:{0}", fileId);
      }
}
```

}

Example of Data.json. But we don't know what field name and data type will be coming.

```
[
  {
    "name": "George",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": "5 years"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nancy",
    "gender": "female",
    "age": "10 years"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alex",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": "3 years"
  },
  {
    "name": "Maximus",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": "7 years"
  } 
]
```